# Branching Systems Differences

Tags: git

There are 3 different branching systems *Feature Branch, Release Branch,* and *Hotfix Branch*

What is the difference between them and what are they used for?

Comment: This was asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585900/what-is-the-difference-between-develop-vs-feature-branch-type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between develop vs. feature branch type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585900/what-is-the-difference-between-develop-vs-feature-branch-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not part of git.

It's one of the git workflows named `git flow`.

All the information is here
https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

There are several common git workflows. GitFlow is only one of them
For example:

- Centralized Workflow
- Feature Branch Workflow
- Gitflow Workflow
- Forking Workflow

---

#### More resoures:

- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

---

#### Git Flow branches

[image]